# How to Mock Breeze.EFContextProvider? UPDATED

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, breeze, repository

```
 /*************************** UPDATED *****************/
```

I have since tried inheriting EFContextProvider so that I can provide the Context as a virtual property to allow testing and can inject my context provider to my repository. This new pattern does work for IOC but Unit Tests are still failing with the following error:

Test method 
MyProj.Infrastructure.MyItemTests.The_MyRepository_MyItems_Should.Return_A_IQuerable_List_of_MyItem_Instances threw exception: 
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

/*************************** UPDATE #2 *****************/
Added repository so my sample code is a little clearer.

```
/********************** THE NEW PATTERN TO SUPPORT IOC ******************************/

public interface IMyDbContextProvider {

    MyDbContext Context { get; }
    string Metadata { get; }
    SaveResult SaveChanges( JObject saveBundle );

}

public class MyDbContext : BaseContext<MyDbContext>, IMyDbContext  {

    public virtual DbSet<MyItem> MyItem{ get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating( DbModelBuilder modelBuilder ) {
        // Use singular table names
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>( );

        // Disable proxy creation and lazy loading; not wanted in this service context.
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new MyItemMap());


    }
}


public class MyContextProvider : EFContextProvider <MyDBContext> , IMyContextProvider {

    public MyContextProvider( ) {

    }
    public virtual MyDbContext Context {
        get { return base.Context; }
    }

    public new string Metadata {
        get {
            return base.Metadata();
        }
    }

    public virtual SaveResult SaveChanges( JObject saveBundle ) {
        return base.SaveChanges( saveBundle );
    }

    protected override bool BeforeSaveEntity( EntityInfo entityInfo ) {
        return base.BeforeSaveEntity( entityInfo );
    }

}

     public interface IMyRepository {

    string Metadata { get; }
    IQueryable<MyItem> GetMyItems{ get; }
    SaveResult SaveChanges( JObject saveBundle );

}
 public class MyRepository : IMyRepository {

    private readonly IMyContextProvider _myContextProvider;

    public MyRepository (IMyContextProvider myContextProvider ) {
        _myContextProvider = myContextProvider;
    }

    public MyDbContext Context {
        get {
            return _myContextProvider.Context;
        }
    }

    public string Metadata {
        get {
            return _myContextProvider.Metadata;
        }
    }

    public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle) {
        return _myContextProvider.SaveChanges( saveBundle );
    }

    public IQueryable<MyItem> GetMyItems() {
        get {
            return Context.MyItems;
        }
    }


}

/**********************My UNIT TEST SET UP FUNCTION AND TEST FUNCTION****/
       [TestInitialize()]
        public void SetUp( ) {
        _querableMyItemData = GetQueryableMyItemData( ); //Returns a list of                  MyItems.AsQueryable()


        _mockMyContextProvider = new Mock<IMyContextProvider>( );

        _mockMyItemSet = new Mock<DbSet<MyItem>>( );
        _mockMyItemSet.As<IQueryable<MyItem>>( ).Setup( m => m.Provider ).Returns( _querableMyItemData.Provider );
        _mockMyItemSet.As<IQueryable<MyItem>>( ).Setup( m => m.Expression ).Returns( _querableMyItemData.Expression );
        _mockMyItemSet.As<IQueryable<MyItem>>( ).Setup( m => m.ElementType ).Returns( _querableMyItemData.ElementType );
        _mockMyItemSet.As<IQueryable<MyItem>>( ).Setup( m => m.GetEnumerator( ) ).Returns( _querableMyItemData.GetEnumerator( ) );


        _mockMyContextProvider.Setup( m => m.Context.Units ).Returns( _mockUnitSet.Object );

    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Return_A_IQuerable_List_of_MyItem_Instances( ) {
        var expectedType = typeof( IEnumerable<MyItem> );

        var myRepository = new MyRepository( _mockMyContextProvider.Object );

        var resultingMyItems = myRepository.GetMyItems();

        Assert.IsInstanceOfType( resultingMyItems, expectedType );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without looking deeply I notice a few things.

First, you didn't tell us what threw the `NullReferenceException`. "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" is not a helpful message so we can't help you either.

Second, you are attempting in `MyDbContextProvider` to virtualize members that are not virtual in the base `EFContextProvider` class. You could make the case that these members ought to be virtual (and I'd stand shoulder to shoulder with you ... please create a UserVoice for that).

But the base class members aren't virtual and so you run the risk that some other method along the way will cast to the base `EFContextProvider` and try to access the unmocked implementation. I don't know that that is happening in your case but it is clearly a possibility.

Third, you are working too hard if your test setup has to mock out members of the `IQueryable` class (e.g., `Provider`, `Expression`, `ElementType`). This is just too much friction for effective testing. You need another way to make your repository testable.

Fourth, because you didn't show the repository (and don't bother ... there's too much code already), I can't tell how `myRepository.myItems` relates to the test mock.

You've got a really good point about `EFContextProvider` being too hard to fake. It is not properly written for testability. To be fair to its author, the EF team didn't help much as the `DbContext`'s `ObjectContext` doesn't look easy to virtualize either.

But you have other problems of your own to trace through first.

Comment: Hi Ward, really appreciate the response.

Comment: Added the sample repository just so my sample code is more complete. Anyways, I noticed that the test setup method did not have the TestInitialize attribute. The test passes now. The reason for the test is ensure I am getting the expected type back from the context when the repository method GetMyItems gets called. It's a bit of overkill to test such a simple method , it's more of a proof of concept so that I know I can actually test the Breeze content provider.

Comment: Turns out only need to mock GetEnumerator to mock your EF6 DbSet. I am concerned that the EFContextProvider properties are virtual, I'm sure this will come in time, hopefully I can help bring it forward :) Again Ward, I really appreciate the input!